# Node.JS & Passport - req.isAuthenicated returns true HOWEVER req.user is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

When accessing my web app, when im at the home page (not logged in) my function that basically does

```
function isNotAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
   if (req.isAuthenticated) {
      res.redirect('/');
   else {
      return next();
   }
}
```

However, when first accessing the home page (not logged in) this function returns true and claims i am logged in.
When checking the req.user, however, it says its undefined.

Anything come to mind as to why my functionality isnt working? its all inside of 1 file called app.js (know this works because there are several youtube tutorials out there that i've followed).
Is it anything to do with the ordering of my app.use functions?

Any help would be lovely, thanks.

EDIT;
Solved! Missed the brackets at the end of the function

Comment: You're currently testing whether `req.isAuthenticated` is truthy - which it will always be since it is a function -, not the result of calling that function.

Comment: @IAmDranged thank you very, very much. Knew it would be down to a tiny user error.

Comment: @IAmDranged if your question is resolved then please remove the question